# Preload effect using CSS and Javascript - Is it possible to pull this css off?

Tags: css

Here's what we are trying to accomplish with no avail so far.

1. Body background must have some grain.
2. Inside the middle image, the background should be white.
3. Since the red part should come up to fill in the shape, the center image should have a transparent background.

I'm not asking about the javascript fill in part.
I'm just wondering if we can accomplish the css part of it.

Any clues ?

Here's a sample:

html:

```
 <body>
    <div>
        <hr/>
        <div class="ornament"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
body {
margin-top: 100px; 
background: url('http://hostmypicture.com/images/fundokairo.png') repeat;
}

hr {
    height: 2px;
    color: #578daf;
    background-color: #578daf;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 9px 0 0 0;
}

.ornament {
    width: 169px;
    height: 169px;
    background: url('http://s23.postimg.org/mtc0673xj/mascara_Kairos.png') 0 50%;
    margin: -84px auto 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9EFdF/

Comment: Here's: 
http://jsfiddle.net/9EFdF/20/

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this:

```
<div style="position:relative;margin:0 auto;display:block;width:150px;height:150px;overflow:hidden;">
<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;border-radius:50px;background-color:red;width:150px;height:150px;">
<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;" id="grainybackground"><img src="mygrainybackground.png"></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;"><img src="my_transparant_great_looking borderimage.png" width="150" height="150">

</div>
```

And then the javascript:

```
document.getElementById("grainybackground").style.top = "-1px";
```

Complete democode on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tLJgC/ :

```
<div style="position:relative;margin:0 auto;display:block;width:156px;height:156px;overflow:hidden;">
<div style="position:absolute;top:3px;left:3px;border-radius:50%;background-color:red;width:150px;height:150px;">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;background-color:grey;width:150px;height:150px;" id="grainybackground"><img src="mygrainybackground.png"></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;border:3px solid black;border-radius:50%;width:147px;height:147px;"><!-- ingnore the border, didn't bother looking for aninside transparent bottlecap background image --><img src="my_transparant_great_looking borderimage.png" width="150" height="150">

</div>
```

and javascript

```
for(c=0;c<150;c++)
{
    window.setTimeout("document.getElementById('grainybackground').style.top=-(0+"+c+")+'px';console.log(0-c)",(100*c));
}
```

**2nd jsfiddle with updated information**

http://jsfiddle.net/tLJgC/2/

```
<body background="http://hostmypicture.com/images/fundokairo.png">
<div style="position:relative;margin:0 auto;display:block;width:156px;height:156px;overflow:hidden">

 <div style="position:absolute;top:3px;left:3px;border-radius:50%;background-color:red;width:150px;height:150px;">

    <div style="position:absolute;top:3px;left:3px;width:150px;height:150px;background-image:url('http://hostmypicture.com/images/fundokairo.png');" id="grainybackground"></div>

<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:150px;height:150px;"><img src="http://s23.postimg.org/mtc0673xj/mascara_Kairos.png" width="150" height="150">

</div>
```

and the javascript

```
for(c=0;c<150;c++)
{
    window.setTimeout("document.getElementById('grainybackground').style.top=-(0+"+c+")+'px';document.getElementById('grainybackground').style.backgroundPosition = '"+c+"px  "+c+"px'",(100*c));
}
```

Comment: I'm not concern about the js part. Only the css. Can you please have a look on tries here. http://jsfiddle.net/j4eH8/4/ - it seems I need an extra white image somewhere. Note that we have background that should be seen, so a gray bar will not work I believe.

Comment: Check this updated fiddle with your images. this is what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/tLJgC/2/

Comment: Yes. Almost. But it blinks. And it should blink. And inside you should have white color, not transparent. Better if we change this mask effect and try canvas or something else, and think about fill. For now, the designer must change the design. :(

Comment: well, this is all the help you're going to get. This is not a write your code for you site. Your question to start with was how to accomplisch this, well simple, with three absolute divs and one transparent.

Answer (score -1):

So basically it's just 3 Divs.

```
<div style="position:relative;background-color:white;width:200px;height:200px">
  <div style="background-color:red;height:100px;width:200px;bottom:0;position:absolute;z-index:10"></div>
  <div style="position:absolute;background-image:shape.png;width:200px;height:200px;z-index:20"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JohanBouveng: so if i don't understand what someone wrote, i should downvote? Hmm interesting.

Comment: I would not consider "It's just 3 divs" and HTML not working in a fiddle as a useful answer. I have not voted anything.